# Помощь по коду для WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Такая ситуация:

Есть у меня произвольное поле[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что оно делает[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть у меня вот такой код

```
<?php $file = get_field('price-field') ?>
<a class="download-box-btn" href="<?php echo $file['url']; ?>">Скачать прайс</a>
```

Такая ситуация:

Ссылка чисто стоит без href[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверно код неправильный, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Это значит, что `$file['url']` есть null. Сделайте $var_dump($file);

Comment: И что мне это должно дать? Я итак знаю благодаря тебе что это null(false)

Comment: Ну хоть немного надо думать. Null =$file['url'] А я спрашиваю, чему равен сам $file. И вообще, программист должен быть чуть более любознателен и чуть менее ленив (var_dump - одна строка)

Comment: Нашел я в чем дело, всё нужно было лишь ID поставить на актуальный, там где <?php $file = get_field('price-field') ?> нужно на <?php $file = get_field('price-field', 160) ?>